# Should we encrypt data in a multi-tenancy product in the cloud?

Tags: encryption, multi-tenancy

We have started to develop a multi-tenancy product.
The product will be deployed in the cloud.
Should we encrypt the product data?
Should the data for each tenant be encrypted using its own key?

**Added**

Each tenant stores the following information:

- a tenant configuration
- a tenant reports

Comment: Is there a reason ***not*** to encrypt?

Comment: Define "product data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shared environment like the cloud, there is always the possibility of data leakage. Therefore encrypting data is a great way to prevent anyone from seeing the data they are not authorized to see. Encryption involves the use of keys and without the access to the proper keys, the data is unreadable and unusable. So the data for each tenant should be encrypted using their own keys.